# Synchronize asynchronously invoked methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, method-invocation

Suppose you are invoking methods *asynchronously* onto the UI thread.

With

```
UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action(_insert), DispatcherPriority.Normal, new object[] { } )
```

you are doing the invocation. From now the runtime environment decides when to execute the method whereas the program continues its 'normal' path of execution.

I am now wondering whether there are any mechanisms to synchronize these asynchronously executed methods when they are returning ? It seems that there are pretty much the same issues as when using multiple threads.

But is a returning method that has been invoked asynchronously before considered to be a thread ? It don't seem so because usual synchronizing efforts like

```
lock (someObject) { //... }
```

or using dedicated locks seem not to work.

**Appendix:**

My actual situation where this issue appears is as follows:

The *asynchronously* invoked method calls as its last statement a `return`method of a static class. Inside this `return` method a commonly used resource (a List) has to be synchronized. Consider the following (overview-like) code-snipped to exemplify:

```
// A simple method that gets invoked asynchronously
public void _insert () {

    // do some code

    StaticClass.Returned();
}


public static StaticClass {

   //...

   public static void Returned () {

        // use a shared resource !
   }

}
```

Comment: `BeginInvoke()` returns a [`DispatcherOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation.aspx) that lets you wait until the asynchronous call completes and get its result; is that what you're looking for?

Comment: well I need a way to make sure that the code inside the `Returned` method get executed mutually exclusive. The DispatcherOperation object seems to be useful tool but I don't think it will help me to achieve this.

Comment: Mutually exclusively to what? You're only showing one access to a shared resource. I find it very very doubtful that `lock` would plain not work, if it doesn't, you probably have more instances of whatever object you're using as the semaphore – check this in a debugger.

Comment: mutually exclusive to all the `Returned()` calls of the `StaticClass`. Suppose I am invoking 1000 times the method `_insert()` which means that the executions of `Returned` are completely mixed up depending on the execution duration of `insert()` and the scheduler that executes the asynchronous invocation.

Comment: Hi Marc. Use a lock statement. It does work. Maybe you have an error somewhere else then. And yes, calls will be mixed up.

Comment: The UIDispatcher runs all invocations on the UI thread, so it only runs one at a time, even when you use BeginInvoke.  As such, a lock shouldn't even be necessary, at least as long as you're not using the resource from any other threads.  I think your problem is not what you believe it to be.

Comment: @DanBryant that's true that the dispatcher runs one method at a time but that only implies that the methods start one after the other. This doesn't hold for their returning since each method takes another duration to execute.

Comment: @Marc, If you queue up two callbacks with the UIDispatcher BeginInvoke, they will never run at the same time.  The first will execute and return completely before the second is called.  This is due to how the callbacks are being dispatched, as part of the UI message pump.  Each callback is called on the UI thread and, when each returns, the next callback in the queue is eligible to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the .NET's asynchronous pattern, a `BackgroundWorker`, or a `ManualResetEvent`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx